# In Servlet the "request.getParts().stream()..." adds a "empty" Part object

Tags: servlets, file-upload

In my `JSP` I have a form where the user can upload a file.

```
<form method="post" action="linkToAction" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="files" type="file" class="form-control-file" multiple="true" >
</form>
```

Reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet), in my `servlet` I get the files uploaded:

```
List<Part> fileParts = request.getParts().stream().filter(part -> "files".equals(part.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If the user doesn't upload anything, I would expect  that the `List<Part> fileParts` would be empty! However, it is not as the above statement adds in the list `fileParts`, an empty `Part`. If the user uploads 1 file, the above statement adds again 1 valid `Part` object.

One quick solution that I thought, is to check the length of the filename:

```
for (Part filePart : fileParts) {
        String fileName = Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString(); /
         if (fileName.length() != 0) {
                   //do my job here
         }
}
```

However, why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if [`Part#getSize()`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/Part.html#getSize--) is bigger than `0`.

```
List<Part> nonEmptyFileParts = request.getParts().stream()
    .filter(part -> "files".equals(part.getName()) && part.getSize() > 0)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The referenced answer has in the meanwhile been updated, thanks.

Comment: do you know why this would happen? I ran into something similar. But in my case I receive the filename in part, but part.getSize() is zero.

Comment: @MudasirAli: Most probably bug in specific browser related to autofill or unselecting files.

Answer (score 1):

you can check the empty condition in `stream` itself.

```
List<Part> fileParts = request.getParts().stream()
                                         .filter(part -> "files".equals(part.getName()) && Objects.nonNull(part.getName()))
                                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```